# How to set the post_author with WooCommerce API when adding a product?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to insert a product in a multivendor environment with WooCommerce, however the API doesn't seem to provide post_author modification because it is single vendor environment) as per the official documentation.
https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#product-properties

Is there a way to set the post_author anyway? i am okay modifying the core WooCommerce files.

Comment: As WooCommerce REST API is fully integrated with the WordPress REST API and as product is a Wordpress custom post, So I think that it should be possible to access the `post_author` through WordPress REST API post: http://v2.wp-api.org/reference/posts/ … But I am not an expert…

Comment: that's an interesting idea thanks